How to Retrieve the Triggering Pipeline's runName in a YAML Release Pipeline
I want to know which pipeline triggered my YAML release pipeline.
Below is a sample YAML file of the release pipeline:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: Dev_Pipeline_Source_BuildPipeline
    source: Dev-Pipeline
    trigger: true
  - pipeline: Main_Pipeline_Source_BuildPipeline
    source: Main-Pipeline
    trigger: true

trigger: none

variables:
- name: CTriggeringAlias
  value: $[variables['Resources.TriggeringAlias']]
- name: CRunName
  value: $( resources.pipeline.$(CTriggeringAlias).runName  )

CTriggeringAlias is correctly evaluated to Dev_Pipeline_Source_BuildPipeline. However, I also want to get the runName of the triggering resource pipeline.
CRunName doesn't seem to work.
Is there any predefined YAML way to find the runName of the triggering build when multiple pipeline resources with triggers enabled are defined?

You can set the variable $(CRunName) in scripts based on the CTriggeringAlias value.
Sample YAML:
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: Dev_Pipeline_Source_BuildPipeline
      source: Dev-Pipeline
      trigger: true
    - pipeline: Main_Pipeline_Source_BuildPipeline
      source: Main-Pipeline
      trigger: true

trigger: none

variables:
  - name: CTriggeringAlias
    value: $(Resources.TriggeringAlias)

steps:
- script: |
    if [ "$(CTriggeringAlias)" == "Dev_Pipeline_Source_BuildPipeline" ]; then
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CRunName]$(resources.pipeline.Dev_Pipeline_Source_BuildPipeline.runName)"
    elif [ "$(CTriggeringAlias)" == "Main_Pipeline_Source_BuildPipeline" ]; then
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CRunName]$(resources.pipeline.Main_Pipeline_Source_BuildPipeline.runName)"
    fi
  displayName: 'Set CRunName variable'

- script: |
      echo "The CTriggeringAlias is $(CTriggeringAlias) "
      echo "The triggering pipeline run name is $(CRunName)"
  displayName: 'Display RunName'

Test result:


This works, but I wanted to solve this using only YAML !!

Hi @osim_ans, it seems that there is currently no way to accomplish what you need using only YAML without using scripts. When you use $(CTriggeringAlias) to define CRunName, the variable CTriggeringAlias ​​is evaluated at runtime, but the expression $(resources.pipeline.$(CTriggeringAlias).runName) will not be dynamically evaluated.  YAML doesn't support dynamic evaluation of variable names based on other variables. This is why the script-based workaround was suggested.

You can also request to improve the feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better.

Instead of:
variables
- name: CTriggeringAlias
  value: $[variables['Resources.TriggeringAlias']]

- name: CRunName
  value: $( resources.pipeline.$(CTriggeringAlias).runName  )

Try concatenating both runName variables:
variables:
  - name: DevCRunName
    value: $(resources.pipeline.Dev_Pipeline_Source_BuildPipeline.runName)

  - name: MainCRunName
    value: $(resources.pipeline.Main_Pipeline_Source_BuildPipeline.runName)

  - name: CRunName
    value: "$(DevCRunName)$(MainCRunName)"

Explanation:

When the pipeline is triggered, only one of the $(DevCRunName) and $(MainCRunName) variables will be set. By concatenating both in $(CRunName) you will retrieve the triggering pipeline's runName.


When the pipeline is triggered, both the $(DevCRunName) and $(MainCRunName) variables are set.

@osim_ans that's strange, in my test pipeline everything worked as expected.
